# Root user cannot read /root/

Tags: linux, terminal, permissions, sudo, root

I added a user called 'kma' to root group. Then I changed permission of /root/ to 770. Which should give the user read, write and execute access since I added him to the root group. But it still gives permission denied error. What am I doing wrong here?

Commands I executed:

```
sudo adduser kma root
sudo chmod 770 /root/
cd /root/ <------- Gives permission error
```

Comment: 1) You're not running as `kma` - unless you omitted the logout / login, 2) you just removed all permissions for "_other_" to deal with `/root/`, so the current user must be the owner, or in the appropriate group.

Comment: I can confirm that I am running as kma and I have logged out and logged back again.

Comment: -bash: cd: /root: No such file or directory

Comment: @Attie They actually probably _added_ group permissions. The default (and correct for security reasosn) permissions for `/root` on pretty much all Linux distributions are `0700`.

Comment: @KMABadshah Did you actually log out, or just close and re-open a terminal window in the same desktop session? It's not my area of expertise, but I've seen posts that suggest opening a new shell/terminal window isn't logging-in... it's just a new instance of bash/whatever running under your existing login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Odd enough for me that I had to restart my computer in order to get the permissions all set up. Anyway, it works fine now

Comment: Please mark an answer as accepted

Comment: That's just how Unix permissions work. It can't update group memberships while the user is logged in, so it requires logging out and logging back in at least (I tend to do full reboots just to be sure).

Answer (score 6):

Make sure that you have logged out and logged back in again, else the group change won't apply. Other than that, what you have written works for me.